# Handle PDF text matrix (Tm) values obtained with CGPDFScanner on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, search, pdf, text, matrix

I am trying to parse pdf content in order to search and highlight text.
I managed with CGPDF stuff to find text with TJ and Tj operators and say in which page the word is. The problem comes with the highlighting.

I followed many other posts such as this [Getting text position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627745/getting-text-position-while-parsing-pdf-with-quartz-2d) or this  [Pdf search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097044/pdf-search-on-the-iphone?tab=votes#tab-top) .

I know the operators for text positioning are Tm (text matrix), TD and Td (T* maybe), But I cant figure out how to use this information.

When I print the Tm value i get a nine-number integer, I can assume this is a 3x3 matrix. I can give you the output:

> 2011-03-23 10:59:07.894 PDFSearch[11035:40b] BT(I) 161361744:
>
> 2011-03-23 10:59:07.896 PDFSearch[11035:40b] TM(I) 161361104:
>
> 2011-03-23 10:59:07.897 PDFSearch[11035:40b] Tf(I) 161361616:
>
> 2011-03-23 10:59:07.899 PDFSearch[11035:40b] TJ: R
>
> 2011-03-23 10:59:07.899 PDFSearch[11035:40b] TJ: e
>
> 2011-03-23 10:59:07.901 PDFSearch[11035:40b] TJ: t
>
> 2011-03-23 10:59:07.901 PDFSearch[11035:40b] TJ: i
>
> 2011-03-23 10:59:07.903 PDFSearch[11035:40b] TJ: co
>
> 2011-03-23 10:59:07.903 PDFSearch[11035:40b] TJ: l
>
> 2011-03-23 10:59:07.905 PDFSearch[11035:40b] TJ: o
>
> 2011-03-23 10:59:07.907 PDFSearch[11035:40b] ET(I) 161361872:

Any idea how to use it to find text positioning? And use it to drow a box on the pdf view with quartz2D?

Thanks :)

Comment: i have same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103281/pdf-file-text-reading-and-searching

Answer (score 3):

The `Tm` operator has six parameters, so you need to use `CGPDFScannerPopNumber` six times which will get you six float values that you can use to construct a `CGAffineTransform`. The `e` and `f` parameters correspond to `tx` and `ty`, otherwise the fields are equally named.

Refer to the [PDF specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) for more details, specifically the chapter about text (page 250 covers the `Tm` operator).

Remember that the operands are popped from a stack, so `f` will be the first value that you get and `a` the last.

Comment: I run into the same problem and this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PDFKitten](https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten/), open source project, they parse all the TJ, Tj, TM and other containers to calculate the text position on screen. It's not perfect, but a start. Searching in pdfs can be tricky, there are so many ways to make pdf display text, some of them are not even fonts at all.