# How to add a note and highlight on UIwebview

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I would like to implement a function like adding a note of a selected text on UIWebview as iBooks and Kobosoft reader

I already created UIMenuItem. But, I don't know how to implement the method for this. Could anybody help in this regard?

I don't know what functionality is used to implement to add note and highlight text as well as store and retrieve

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView is implemented in such a way that you may be able to add notes to a certain portion of the text of a web page or PDF loaded into the view, but highlighting is impossible because the APIs don't allow it.  iBooks and Kobo (and kindle to some extent) utilize a combination of the [CGPDF](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101) APIs and a little Core Animation magic for the highlighting of PDFs, and store it in the metadata of the PDF.  Reading and writing to the metadata store is easy, however rendering the highlights is a challenge that involves some [interesting math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403610/handle-pdf-text-matrix-tm-values-obtained-with-cgpdfscanner-on-iphone-ipad).